# Firestore messaging data payload not always working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firestore messaging service with cloud functions to build a notification and send it to a device, this works whether the app is in the background or foreground however some of the data seems missing if the app is in the background or killed, here is a log from my onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage) method when the app is in the background or killed

```
 Log.d(MYTAG,"profile image : " + profileImage);
 Log.d(MYTAG,"name : " + author);


 D/FBMsg: profile image : 
 D/FBMsg: name : Jon Doe
```

here 'author' and 'profileImage' are both strings and author is fine but profile image is blank. Here is the same logs but from when the app is in the foreground

```
D/FBMsg: profile image : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/
aimessage-b2502.appspot.com/o/abS2f5qVHyOpj8kN3ViEnYVTTjn1%2Fprofile_pics
%2F20180612_101808?alt=media&token=a95f4c25-af15-42fe-9629-b44815658cac
D/FBMsg: name : Jon Doe
```

I've read through the docs and I get that notification payloads won't fire if the app is in the foreground but data payloads should fire regardless and that doesn't explain why I would get part of the data and not all of it can anyone help?
Here is my cloud function for sending the notification

```
   const payload = {
            data : {
                TITLE : senderName + " sent you a message.",
                BODY : notificationBody,
                USER_NAME : senderName,
                USER_NUMBER : message['sender'],
                USER_IMAGE : senderImage,
                CLICK_ACTION : "MessageListActivity",
                MESSAGE : message['message'],
                IMAGE : imageMessage,
                TYPE : message['data_type']
            }
        }
```

and here is how I retrieve the values plus logs and outputs

```
    String author = data.get("USER_NAME");
    String title = data.get("TITLE");
    String body = data.get("BODY");
    String id = data.get("USER_NUMBER");
    String message = data.get("MESSAGE");
    String type = data.get("TYPE");
    String image = data.get("IMAGE");
    String profileImage = data.get("USER_IMAGE");
    String shortMessage = "";
    Intent intent;

    Log.d(MYTAG,"sent image : " + image);
    Log.d(MYTAG,"title : " + title);
    Log.d(MYTAG,"body : " + body);
    Log.d(MYTAG,"id : " + id);
    Log.d(MYTAG,"message : " + message);
    Log.d(MYTAG,"type : " + type);
    Log.d(MYTAG,"image : " + image);
    Log.d(MYTAG,"profile image : " + profileImage);
```

**App in background Output**

```
D/FBMsg:sent image : 
D/FBMsg: title : Jon Doe sent you a message.
D/FBMsg: body : Hi
D/FBMsg: id : abS2f5qVHyOpj8kN3ViEnYVTTjn1
D/FBMsg: message : Hi
D/FBMsg: type : TEXT
D/FBMsg: image : 
D/FBMsg: profile image :
```

**App in foreground Output**

```
D/FBMsg: sent image : 
D/FBMsg: title : Jon Doe sent you a message.
D/FBMsg: body : Fvrvvr
D/FBMsg: id : abS2f5qVHyOpj8kN3ViEnYVTTjn1
D/FBMsg: message : Fvrvvr
D/FBMsg: type : TEXT
D/FBMsg: image : 
D/FBMsg: profile image : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/
aimessageb2502.appspot.com/o/abS2f5qVHyOpj8kN3ViEnYVTTjn1%2F
profile_pics%2F20180612_101808?alt=media&token=a95f4c25-af15-42fe-9629- 
b44815658cac
```

it seems like it just doesn't like the URL any ideas?

Comment: also Ive checked with my cloud function and it isnt the problem

Comment: Data messages are handled the same in the background and foreground. Could you include how you are sending the message?

Comment: gladly however I'm not sure what you mean, I update information in my database and it triggers a cloud function that sends my notification, I use console log on the image url in my cloud function and it prints fine everytime

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this, could you try sending only the URL and see if you see the same effect (foreground vs background)?